# Array of buses in superCollider

Tags: supercollider

I have a Synth generated with a do:

```
(
SynthDef(\siny, { arg freq, outBus=0; Out.ar( outBus, SinOsc.ar(freq!2,0,0.2) ) } ).send(s);
SynthDef(\filter, { arg cFreq,q=0.8, inBus; Out.ar( 0, BPF.ar(In.ar(inBus), cFreq!2, 1/q ) ) } ).send(s);

)

(
~sourceOut = Bus.audio(s);
~sine_Group = ParGroup.new;
z = [100,500,1000,1500,250];

{
z.do({ arg val; Synth.head(~sine_Group, \siny, [\freq: val, \outBus: ~sourceOut]) });
z.do({ arg val; Synth.after(~sine_Group, \filter, [\inBus: ~sourceOut, \cFreq: 200] ) });

}.play;
)
```

Right now, my understanding is that, output of multiple instances of Synth \siny get mixed in the bus ~sourceOut, and goes as an input into synth \filter

What i actually want to do is to have a one-to-one connection between the multiple instances of \siny and \filter.. Could I use an array of busses to connect them? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Here I've modified your code minimally. First I made `~sourceOut` an array of Busses rather than a single Bus. Second, inside the `do` loops I made use of the fact that the main iteration functions in SuperCollider can provide a second `index` argument as well as each item itself. Thirdly I use that `index` argument to select the desired Bus:

```
(
z = [100,500,1000,1500,250];
~sourceOut = z.collect{ Bus.audio(s) };
~sine_Group = ParGroup.new;

{
z.do({ arg val, index; Synth.head(~sine_Group, \siny, [\freq: val, \outBus: ~sourceOut[index]]) });
z.do({ arg val, index; Synth.after(~sine_Group, \filter, [\inBus: ~sourceOut[index], \cFreq: 200] ) });

}.play;
)
```

Depending on your needs, you might also like to look at `NodeProxy` which is useful for prototyping and live coding, and provides some tricks for plugging synths' output into each other.

Comment: Hi @Dan_S, I have another question , its more like a follow up. Could you go over it?

[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167856/connecting-multiple-stages-of-parallel-synths-with-array-of-buses-in-supercoll)