# Connecting multiple stages of parallel synths, with array of buses, in superCollider

Tags: supercollider

When I have 2 stages of multiple parallel synths, I am able to connect it with an array of buses. (Thanks to Dan S for the answer to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076874/array-of-buses-in-supercollider/35100028#35100028)). When there is a 3 stage, this doesn't seem to work.

```
(
SynthDef(\siny, { arg freq, outBus=0; Out.ar( outBus, SinOsc.ar(freq!2,0,0.2) ) } ).send(s);
SynthDef(\filter, { arg cFreq,q=0.8, inBus, outBus=0; Out.ar( outBus, BPF.ar(In.ar(inBus), cFreq!2, 1/q ) ) } ).send(s);
)

(
var z = [100,500,1000,1500,200];
~sourceOut = z.collect{ Bus.audio(s) };
~sineOut = z.collect{ Bus.audio(s) };
~sine_Group = ParGroup.new;
~myGroup    = ParGroup.new;

{
z.do({ arg val, index; Synth( \siny, [\freq: val, \outBus: ~sourceOut[index]], ~sine_Group ) });
z.do({ arg val, index; Synth.after(~sine_Group, \filter, [\inBus: ~sourceOut[index], \outBus: ~sineOut[index],\cFreq: 200, \q: 20 ], ~myGroup) });
z.do({ arg val, index; Synth.after(~myGroup, \filter, [\inBus: ~sineOut[index], \cFreq: 200, \q: 20]) });

}.play;
)
```

Another harm that I am doing here is, everytime I stop and run the synth, new instances of busses are created and eventually run out of audio buses. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code (some irrelevant with your question):

a. `send(s)` is a reminiscent of the past, these days simply `add` is preferable - you may consult the documentation for their differences.

b. it's not a good practice to mix local variables `var` with environmental ones (such as `~sourceOut`) unless there is some good reason.

c. `.collect(func)` (or directly `collect{/*function body here*/})` when send to an array results to another array where each element is the result of the `func` with the respective element of the original array passed as an argument. So here:

```
var z = [100,500,1000,1500,200];
~sourceOut = z.collect{ Bus.audio(s) };
~sineOut = z.collect{ Bus.audio(s) };
```

you don't use the original numbers anywhere, you just create two arrays containing 5 Audio buses each. Directly doing so would be less confusing and more explicit:

```
~sourceOut = Array.fill(5,{Bus.audio(s)});
~sineOut = Array.fill(5,{Bus.audio(s)});
```

d. there's no point in calling z.do three times.. you can call it just once and put the rest in the same function.

e. check you routings... You have two **parallel** groups and you're merely saying that I want these synths on that group and these others **after** that other group.. What you really want to say is that I want these `Synth`s after those `Synth`s on that group.

f. you don't free your Buses or your Synths when done... this is a memory leak :)

g. you call `play` on a function that want to *evaluate* really... you should call `value` instead.

This code does produces sound and cleans up everything when don, note however that the result is pretty boring because you've filtered all the higher-end.

```
s.waitForBoot({ // this is a routine

    var frequencies = [100,500,1000,1500,200];
    var sources = Array.fill(frequencies.size,{Bus.audio(s)});
    var filters = Array.fill(frequencies.size,{Bus.audio(s)});
    var parGroups = Array.fill(2,{ParGroup.new});
    var sineSynths;
    var firstOrderFilters;
    var secondOrderFilters;

    SynthDef(\siny, {
        arg freq, outBus=0;
        Out.ar( outBus, SinOsc.ar(freq!2,0,0.2));
    }).add;
    SynthDef(\filter, {
        arg cFreq,q=0.8, inBus, outBus=0;
        Out.ar( outBus, BPF.ar(In.ar(inBus), cFreq!2, 1/q ) )
    }).add;
    s.sync; // wait for the synthdefs to load

    frequencies.do{ arg freq, index;
        sineSynths = sineSynths.add( Synth(\siny, [\freq: freq.postln, \outBus: sources[index]],
            parGroups[0])); // create synths and add them in the sineSynths Array
        firstOrderFilters = firstOrderFilters.add(
            Synth.after(sineSynths[index], \filter, [\inBus: sources[index],
                \outBus: filters[index], \cFreq: 200, \q: 20 ], parGroups[1]));
        secondOrderFilters = secondOrderFilters.add(
            Synth.after(firstOrderFilters[index], \filter, [\inBus: filters[index],
                \outBus: 0, \cFreq: 200, \q: 20 ], parGroups[1]));
    };

    10.wait; // wait 10 seconds;

    // clean up everything
    sineSynths.do{arg i; i.free};
    firstOrderFilters.do{arg i; i.free};
    secondOrderFilters.do{arg i; i.free};
    sources.do{arg i; i.free};
    filters.do{arg i; i.free};
});
```